# Lambda lifetime explanation for C++20 coroutines

Tags: c++, c++20, folly, c++-coroutine

[Folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly/tree/master/folly/experimental/coro) has a useable library for C++20 style coroutines.

In the Readme it claims:

> IMPORTANT: You need to be very careful about the lifetimes of temporary lambda objects. Invoking a lambda coroutine returns a folly::coro::Task that captures a reference to the lambda and so if the returned Task is not immediately co_awaited then the task will be left with a dangling reference when the temporary lambda goes out of scope.

I tried to make a MCVE for the example they provided, and was confused about the results.
Assume the following boilerplate for all the following examples:

```cpp
#include <folly/experimental/coro/Task.h>
#include <folly/experimental/coro/BlockingWait.h>
#include <folly/futures/Future.h>
using namespace folly;
using namespace folly::coro;

int main() {
    fmt::print("Result: {}\n", blockingWait(foo()));
}
```

I compiled the following with address sanitizer to see if there would be any dangling references.

**EDIT: clarified question**

### **Question**: Why does the second example not trigger an ASAN warning?

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines):

> When a coroutine reaches the co_return statement, it performs the following:
>
> ...
>
> - or calls promise.return_value(expr) for co_return expr where expr has non-void type
> - destroys all variables with automatic storage duration in reverse order they were created.
> - calls promise.final_suspend() and co_await's the result.

Thus perhaps the temporary lambda's state is not actually destroyed until the result is returned, because `foo` itself is a coroutine?

---

**ASAN ERROR**: I assume 'i' doesn't exist when the coroutine is waited on

```cpp
auto foo() -> Task<int> {
    auto task = [i=1]() -> folly::coro::Task<int> {
        co_return i;
    }(); // lambda is destroyed after this semicolon
    return task;
}
```

---

**NO ERROR** -- why?

```cpp
auto foo() -> Task<int> {
  auto task = [i=1]() -> folly::coro::Task<int> {
      co_return i;
  }();
  co_return co_await std::move(task);
}
```

---

**ASAN ERROR**: Same problem as first example?

```cpp
auto foo() -> folly::SemiFuture<int> {
    auto task = [i=1]() -> folly::coro::Task<int> {
        co_return i;
    }();
    return std::move(task).semi();
}
```

---

**NO ERROR** ...and for good measure, just returning a constant (no lambda state captured) works fine. Compare to first example:

```cpp
auto foo() -> Task<int> {
    auto task = []() -> folly::coro::Task<int> {
        co_return 1;
    }();
    return task;
}
```

Comment: `auto task = [i=1]() -> folly::coro::Task<int> { co_await something; co_return i; }` will trigger the UAF.

Comment: I don't mind downvotes as feedback, but I'm not sure why the downvotes. Question too ambiguous? Not enough research?

Comment: C++ community...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This problem is not unique or specific to lambdas; it could affect any callable object that simultaneously stores internal state and happens to be a coroutine. But this problem is easiest to encounter when making a lambda, so we'll look at it from that perspective.

First, some terminology.

In C++, a "lambda" is an *object*, not a function. A lambda object has an overload for the function call operator `operator()`, which invokes the code written into the lambda body. That is all a lambda is, so when I subsequently refer to "lambda", I am talking about a C++ object and *not a function*.

In C++, being a "coroutine" is a property of a *function*, not an object. A coroutine is a function that appears identical to a normal function from the outside, but which is implemented internally in such a way that its execution can be suspended. When a coroutine is suspended, execution returns to the function that directly invoked/resumed the coroutine.

The execution of the coroutine can later be resumed (the mechanism for doing so is not something I'm going to discuss much here). When a coroutine is suspended, all of the stack variables within that coroutine function up to the point of the coroutine's suspension are preserved. This fact is what allows resumption of the coroutine to work; it's what makes coroutine code seem like normal C++ even though execution can happen in a very disjoint fashion.

A coroutine is not an object, and a lambda is not a function. So, when I use the seemingly contradictory term "coroutine lambda", what I *really* mean is an object whose `operator()` overload happens to be a coroutine.

Are we clear? OK.

Important Fact #1:

When the compiler evaluates a lambda expression, it creates a prvalue of the lambda type. This prvalue will (eventually) initialize an object, usually as a temporary within the scope of the function that evaluated the lambda expression in question. But it could be a stack variable. Which it is doesn't really matter; what matters is that, when you evaluate a lambda expression, there is an object which is in every way like a regular C++ object of any user-defined type. That means it has a lifetime.

Values "captured" by the lambda expression are essentially member variables of the lambda object. They could be references or values; it doesn't really matter. When you use a capture name in the lambda body, you are really accessing the named member variable of the lambda object. And the rules about member variables in a lambda object are no different from the rules about member variables in any user-defined object.

Important Fact #2:

A coroutine is a function which can be suspended in such a way that its "stack values" can be preserved, so that it can resume its execution later. For our purposes, "stack values" include all function parameters, any temporary objects generated up to the point of suspension, and any function local variables declared in the function up to that point.

And *that is all* that gets preserved.

A member function can be a coroutine, but the coroutine suspension mechanism does not care about member *variables*. Suspension only applies to the execution of that function, not to the object *around* that function.

Important Fact #3:

The main point of having coroutines at all is to be able to suspend a function's execution and have that function's execution resumed by some other code. This likely will be in some disparate part of the program, and usually in a thread distinct from the place where the coroutine was *initially* invoked. That is, if you create a coroutine, you expect that the caller of that coroutine will continue its execution in *parallel* with your coroutine function's execution. If the caller does wait for your execution to complete, the caller does so *at its choosing*, not yours.

That's *why* you made it a coroutine to begin with.

The point of the `folly::coro::Task` object is to essentially keep track of the coroutine's post-suspension execution, as well as marshall any return value(s) generated by it. It also may permit one to schedule the resumption of some other code after the execution of the coroutine it represents. So a `Task` could represent a long series of coroutine executions, with each feeding data to the next.

The important fact here is that the coroutine starts in one place like a normal function, but it can end at some other point in time *outside* of the callstack that invoked it initially.

So, let's put those these facts together.

If you're a function that creates a lambda, then you (at least for some period of time) have a prvalue of that lambda, right? You will either store it yourself (as a temporary or stack variable) or you will pass it to someone else. Either yourself or that someone else will at some point invoke the `operator()` of that lambda. At that point, the lambda object must be a live, functional object, or you've got a much bigger problem on your hands.

So the immediate caller of a lambda has an lambda object, and the lambda's function starts executing. If it is a coroutine lambda, then this coroutine will likely at some point suspend its execution. This transfers program control back to the immediate caller, the code which holds the lambda object.

And that's where we encounter the consequences of IF#3. See, the lambda object's lifetime is controlled by the code which initially invoked the lambda. But the execution of the coroutine *within* that lambda is controlled by some arbitrary, external code. The system which governs this execution is the `Task` object returned to the immediate caller by the initial execution of the coroutine lambda.

So there's the `Task` which represents the coroutine function's execution. But there's also the lambda object. These are both objects, but they are *separate objects*, with distinct lifetimes.

IF#1 tells us that lambda captures are member variables, and the rules of C++ tell us that the lifetime of a member is governed by the lifetime of the object it is a member of. IF#2 tells us that these member variables are not preserved by the coroutine suspension mechanism. And IF#3 tells us that the coroutine execution is governed by the `Task`, whose execution can be (very) unrelated to the initial code.

If you put this all together, what we find is that, if you have a coroutine lambda which captures variables, then the lambda object which was invoked *must* continue to exist until the `Task` (or whatever governs continued coroutine execution) has completed the coroutine lambda's execution. If it doesn't, then the coroutine lambda's execution may attempt to access member variables of an object whose lifetime has ended.

How exactly you do that is up to you.

---

Now, let's look at your examples.

Example 1 fails for obvious reasons. The code invoking the coroutine creates a temporary object representing the lambda. But that temporary goes out of scoped immediately. No effort is made to ensure that the lambda remains in existence while the `Task` is executing. This means that it is possible for the coroutine to be resumed after the lambda object it lives within has been destroyed.

That's bad.

Example 2 is actually just as bad. The lambda temporary is destroyed immediately after the creation of `tasks`, so merely `co_await`ing on it shouldn't matter. However, ASAN may simply not have caught it because it now happens inside of a coroutine. If your code had instead been:

```
Task<int> foo() {
  auto func = [i=1]() -> folly::coro::Task<int> {
      co_return i;
  };

  auto task = func();

  co_return co_await std::move(task);
}
```

Then the code would be fine. The reason being that `co_await`ing on a `Task` causes the current coroutine to suspend its execution until the last thing in the `Task` is done, and that "last thing" is `func`. And since stack objects are preserved by coroutine suspension, `func` will continue to exist so long as this coroutine does.

Example 3 is bad for the same reasons as Example 1. It doesn't matter how you use the return value of the coroutine function; if you destroy the lambda before the coroutine finishes execution, your code is broken.

Example 4 is technically just as bad as all the rest. However, because the lambda is captureless, it never needs to access any members of the lambda object. It never actually accesses any object whose lifetime has ended, so ASAN never notices that the object around the coroutine is dead. It's UB, but it's UB that's unlikely to hurt you. If you had explicitly extracted a function pointer from the lambda, even that UB wouldn't happen:

```
Task<int> foo() {
    auto func = +[]() -> folly::coro::Task<int> { //The + extracts a function pointer from a captureless lambda for complex, convoluted reasons.
        co_return 1;
    };
    auto task = func();
    return task;
}
```

Comment: This answers my question by clarifying the relationship between lambdas and coroutines. Specifically, pointing out that a Task returned by executing a lambda is tied to the `()` operator for that lambda was especially helpful in combining my existing knowledge of lambdas with coroutines.

Comment: For your last example using a unary `+` to convert to a function pointer, could one also use an immediately invoked lambda expression and avoid UB?

Comment: @MikeLui: Immediately invoking the lambda is *exactly the same* as what you did in your example.

Comment: I think I used the wrong language in my above comment. So in your last example, the lambda is also just a prvalue and immediately destroyed, because instead of immediately invoking the lambda, you instead perform a unary operation on the prvalue and get the result of that unary operation (the function pointer, thus the lambda is destroyed after). If you immediately call the returned function pointer instead of storing it in a value, that would also avoid UB?

Comment: @MikeLui: Yes that would work, but why bother? Lambdas are really long expressions already; making the user read both a prefix *and* a suffix to that long expression just to figure out what is going on makes the code obtuse. Just use a variable; it's not going to kill you.

Comment: It was a purely academic question :)

Comment: One way of putting the limitation on member-function coroutines is that it is their implicit `this` parameter that is preserved in the coroutine state, not the object to which it refers (which of course already has its own unrelated storage and lifetime).

Comment: Why exactly do you think the last example has undefined behavior?  We can `delete this;`, so simply “being” in a member function for a dead object is OK; the member function is (initially) called before the lambda is destroyed, and I don’t see any rules that say that *resuming* such a function is bad.

Comment: It isn't really true that coroutines are always used with threads, and threads are not even the culprit here, it's just an issue of the coroutine object's lifetime if you are going to access captured member variables.

Comment: @SeattleCplusplus: "*It isn't really true that coroutines are always used with threads*" This seems a non-sequitur, as I never claimed that they are "always used with threads". I said "usually", and that's true. And nowhere did I claim that the issue was specifically about threads.

Comment: @DavisHerring Are you saying that `this` is copied into the coroutine on all compilers? Is it safe to capture and reference `this`, even beyond the lifetime of the lambda?

Comment: @lufinkey: Sure, but `this` is just a pointer, so there’s very little one can do with it once its referent has been destroyed.

Comment: @DavisHerring Makes sense, the semantics of how things are captured is just very difficult to parse in the c++ standard. I just had an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68629329/is-it-safe-to-capture-this-in-a-coroutine-lambda-c?noredirect=1#comment121288325_68629329) capturing other pointer or reference values beyond the lambda lifetime so I'm wondering why `this` is treated differently

Comment: @lufinkey: It’s not different, but it can dangle like any other pointer/reference.  It is possible to capture `*this` if desired.

Comment: So are captured references always copied to the coroutine itself?  When I was looking at the c++ documentation, it said `It is
unspecified whether additional unnamed non-static data members are declared in the closure type for entities
captured by reference.`, which I interpreted as meaning captured references /may/ get copied to the coroutine itself, but they might also be members of the lambda object, in which case if the lambda goes out of scope, the reference to the reference member on the closure type would point to dead memory

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround if you have a custom promise type, or your promise can queue work to run after your task finishes.

```
auto coLambda(auto&& executor) {
    return [executor=std::move(executor)]<typename ...Args>(Args&&... args) {
        using ReturnType = decltype(executor(args...));
        // copy the lambda into a new std::function pointer
        auto exec = new std::function<ReturnType(Args...)>(executor);
        // execute the lambda and save the result
        auto result = (*exec)(args...);
        // call custom method to save lambda until task ends
        coCaptureVar(result, exec);
        return result;
    };
}
```

Example of custom method for saving the lambda var (might vary depending on your promise type):

```
template<typename T>
void coCaptureVar(Task<T> task, auto* var) {
    task.finally([var]() {
        delete var;
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
// just wrap your lambda in coLambda
coLambda([=]() -> Task<T> {
    // ...
    // you're free to use captured variables as needed, even if coroutine suspends
})
```