# Can asio co_composed lambda function capture this pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, coroutine, asio

I've read this Q&A.
[Lambda lifetime explanation for C++20 coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60592174/lambda-lifetime-explanation-for-c20-coroutines/60604095#60604095)

If I understand correctly, lambda expression with capture something is not safe if the lambda expression is used as coroutine function.

Now I come up with the following question.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/co_composed.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;

struct foo {
    template <typename CompletionToken>
    auto mf1(
        CompletionToken&& token
    ) {
        return asio::async_initiate<
            CompletionToken,
            void()
        >(
            asio::experimental::co_composed<
                void()
            >(
                [](                 // capture nothing
                    auto /*state*/,
                    foo& self
                ) -> void {
                    // co_await some_async_function(asio::deferred);
                    self.val_++;    // accesses member variables via self
                    co_return {};
                }
            ),
            token,
            std::ref(*this)
        );
    }

    template <typename CompletionToken>
    auto mf2(
        CompletionToken&& token
    ) {
        return asio::async_initiate<
            CompletionToken,
            void()
        >(
            asio::experimental::co_composed<
                void()
            >(
                [this](              // capture this.
                    auto /*state*/
                ) -> void {
                    // co_await some_async_function(asio::deferred);
                    val_++;          // accesses member variables
                    co_return {};
                }
            ),
            token
        );
    }

    int val_ = 0;
};

asio::awaitable<void> proc() {
    foo f;
    co_await f.mf1(asio::deferred);
    co_await f.mf2(asio::deferred);
    std::cout << f.val_ << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    asio::co_spawn(
        ioc.get_executor(),
        proc(),
        asio::detached
    );
    ioc.run();
}
```

godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/d7snvYYqb

class `foo` has two member functions. Both member functions do the same thing. They are async function implemented by `co_composed`.
`mf1()`'s lambda expression captures nothing, and passed `*this` as `self`. `val_` is accessed through `self`. I think that it is safe.

`mf2()`'s lambda expression captures this pointer. `val_` is accessed through this pointer. Is it safe?
Before accessing `val_`, co_await could be placed, so the context could be switched and switched back. In this case, captured this pointer is treated well?
I suspect that it could be unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes it safe to use a reference? The reference must point to a valid object of the expected type.

When would that cease to be the case? When the lifetime of the referred-to object ends, or when the object is otherwise invalidated (e.g. by being moved from).

In your code none of the two are applicable. `foo` lives in Asio's coro frame, which is stable.

Your capture is **safe**.

### Side-tangent:

It's critical to observe here that `this` refers to the `foo` instance, not the lambda. The lambda instance is likely moved along the async call chain, so can not be considered stable. This might be relevant when you have value-captures and accidentally pass references to them around. Luckily you would probably not have a need for much state in the lambda because the `foo` instance basically

### UPDATE

That Side-tangent proves to be prophetic. In the comments we analyzed down to this case:

**[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/rs466TP7M)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    auto bar = [v = 42]() -> asio::awaitable<void> { assert(v); co_return; };

    co_spawn(ioc, bar, asio::detached);   // fine
    co_spawn(ioc, bar(), asio::detached); // fine
    co_spawn(ioc,
        [v = 42]() -> asio::awaitable<void> { assert(v); co_return; },
        asio::detached); // fine

    // OOPS: this one is broken
    co_spawn(ioc,
        [p = 42] -> asio::awaitable<void> { assert(p); co_return; }(),
        asio::detached);

    ioc.run();
}
```

You'll note that when the lambda is a temporary, it leads to an `awaitable<>` with a dangling reference to the lambda instance. This makes it a tiny bit clearer, maybe:

```
// OOPS: this one is broken
// aw stores a reference to a temporary lambda instance
asio::awaitable<void> aw = [p = 42] -> asio::awaitable<void> { assert(p); co_return; }();

// the lambda instance is gone, but the coroutine is going to invoke its `operator()() const` still:    
co_spawn(ioc, std::move(aw), asio::detached);
```

It's extremely subtle, and you can avoid it by *not invoking the lambda*, but instead passing it by value.

Comment: thank you the answser. I noticed that I didn't explain well what is the point of the question. Let's say the lifetime of `f` is managed well. So in anywhere of mf1() and mf2(), `f` is living. I suspect that `this` is not resumed well in some case even if `f` is living. I wrote a new example code that uses co_spawn instead of co_composed.
 https://godbolt.org/z/fbhfsaeTe

Comment: mf2() captures `this` points to `f`. The inner lambda expression creates a new coro frame and `this` is out of the coro frame. I guess that `this` would not be resumed well. So mf1() uses `foo& self`, self is a parameter of the inner lambda expression, so it is resumed well, I guess. Am I misunderstand something?

Comment: Both approaches are equivalent. All you do is copy a pointer to a valid object in various ways. What matters is that the pointer points to a valid object. The fact that your `proc` will not complete unless all the detached coros have does guarantee it. The "new" version seems heavily contrived. I can only assume that the inner coro would in actually *not* be a coro, but some kind of third-party API adapted.  Because that's the only reason I can imagine for the extra indirection with detached operations.

Comment: Hmm... What do you think address sanitizer error on this code https://godbolt.org/z/hGd8Gh9sE  ? The outer co_spawn capture `f` as reference on `#if 1`, then address sanitizer reported error. If `f` is passed as referece argument, then no error (`#if 0`). I think that both `f` is living because `ioc.run();` is working. What is the difference between outer co_spawn and inner co_spawn? At first, I suspected address sanitizer behavior, but actually undefined behavior happens in similar code (not this one).

Comment: Oof. Yeah, that makes no sense. I don't agree with the ASAN. So I suspect a false positive or bad code-gen, in which case there might actually be UB as a result. What annoys me is that GCC also causes this, making me gaslight myself that I'm missing something (but... I don't?) I have further minimized the code to this, with some additional analysis output https://godbolt.org/z/1EPqscf95 - hope this might help you get closer, if only closer to a bug report?

Comment: According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60592174/lambda-lifetime-explanation-for-c20-coroutines/60604095#60604095 , coroutine only care (for resume) about lambda expression parameters and local variables in the lambda expression. Because they are in the call stack. However, captured variable (pointer, reference included) are not cared because they are automatically generated class' member variable. C++20 coroutine doesn't care about it. That is the reason I refer the Q&A in the beginning of my question.

Comment: But all that is irrelevant w.r.t. the lifetime of the `foo f;` variable as well as the validity of references/pointers to (members of) it.

Comment: I'm having a brainwave. I think I might see another problem. Yup. Checks out: https://godbolt.org/z/7nbYzqMKc Now I'm going to torture my brain for some time to see whether this is a false positive or a very very subtle issue that *actually* exists. It's also bed-time, so I'll be back tomorrow!

Comment: Maybe you can figure this one out? https://godbolt.org/z/Tdhnn7vzc should be clearer side-by-side and even more minimal

Comment: I think that the key point is not `f`'s lifetime, but what entity is resumable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60592174/lambda-lifetime-explanation-for-c20-coroutines/60604095#60604095 `Important Fact #2:` said that "A member function can be a coroutine, but the coroutine suspension mechanism does not care about member variables. Suspension only applies to the execution of that function, not to the object around that function.". The member function means the generated lambda class's operator(), I think. It seems that you think `Important Fact #2:` is not true. That is key point, I think

Comment: Bingo. The whole question was a red herring. `foo` is FINE, like I analyzed. However, a temporary lambda, when invoked will end up capturing a reference to the temporary lambda in the awaitable.

Comment: I'm actually not sure anymore whether your last comment was on the same page, however I updated my answer with the explanation I think explains the situation. Note the even simpler repro

Comment: So I was wrong in the end: the linked Q&A **was** relevant to the problem you were having, just not to the question you were asking. And I learned to be way more vigilant of this pitfall in the future. Because it's one that I anticipate seeing more often in the future.

Comment: I read your updated answer. And I noticed that co_spawn has 6 overloads. The first 4 are taking awaitable parameter and the rest 2 are taking nullary callable, as the second parameter.
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/co_spawn.html
That is why, both invoked and not invoked lamda expression are accpepted.

Comment: How about co_composed ? I wrote this example https://godbolt.org/z/oqY891rdo
At the line 74, outer lambda is not invoked, so callable version of co_spawn is used. mf2() uses captured variables. Is it safe? If something like awaitable overload of co_spawn equivalent process is used in the co_composed implementation, it could be unsafe. As far as I read the code, it is not used. So co_composed can capture variables including `this` as long as captured value is living, do you agree?
BTW, there is no code example that co_composed with capture something in asio.

Comment: Co_composed was never an issue (which is why my answer was what it was). Any issue was with the code you posted in the comments. In general, don't go diving into implementation details. Just look at the documented interface. `co_composed` only ever takes a coro (a function object), never an awaitable. The problem arises with an awaitable returned from a temporary lambda expression. Even `co_spawn` interface is pretty simple: as long as you pass a valid coro **or** a valid awaitable, you're fine. The  examples in the comments didn't all pass a valid awaitable leading to ASAN complaints.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I guess I finally understand. The last my vague part was "Why pass the value as lambda invocation argument doesn't cause access violation?". I worte lambda equivalent class and tested it https://godbolt.org/z/P5T77sE1a
Actually, as you mentioned, the access is happend after the class lambda temporary object is destroyed. So accessing member variable `p` causes access violation, but parameter `a` is still living.
This difference lead me confusion (Something like "Perhaps some coroutine specific variable treat could be hidden").

Comment: Now, I am clear! 
I think that when I use co_spawn(), the function object parameter version of co_spawn() overload is the first candidate for me.

Thank you for taking your time to long discussion with me.

Comment: I learn a lot doing this, so no worries. Thanks for bringing the interesting questions